# Erro ao gerar apk no ionic framework v 1

Tags: ionic

Olá,

Estou com um tremendo erro ao tentar gerar o apk do android com o ionic framework, não estou conseguindo corrigir o problema, coloquei o log do cmd neste [link](http://pastebin.com/ApjH03Fa).

Desde já agradeço

http://pastebin.com/ApjH03Fa

Answer (score 1):

*Atualize seu SDK*

```
android list sdk
android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra
```

*Atualize as configurações do Ionic Android*

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```